# How to split the output of .extract used in the PDFQuery scraping library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have a problem with pdf query library. I have been trying to figure this out the last few days but I can't seem to figure it out.

**Code:**

```
def data_validation(x,y,x1,y1,pdf,width_scale,height_scale):

    values = pdf.extract([
        ('with_formatter', 'text'),
        ('with_parent','LTPage[pageid=\'1\']'),
        ('values', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("%s,%s,%s,%s")' % ((x1*width_scale), ((800-y)*height_scale), (x*width_scale), ((800-y1)*height_scale)))
    ])

    return values
```

The input variables for the function (data_validation) is a bounding box that covers two objects (bounding box values), but the output seems to have merged to 1 value (output).

**Bounding box values:**

```
bbox #1 - Exhibit A Sample Contract
bbox #2 - Sample Contract
```

**Output:**

```
{' values': 'Exhibit A Sample Contract Sample Contract'}
```

Shouldn't the output be {' values': 'Exhibit A Sample Contract', 'Sample Contract'}, a key with 2 values?

Hopefully someone can help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some deliberating with a similar issue I had myself, I thought I'd post my fix as this would have greatly helped along the way.

Instead of asking pyquery to format the XML nodes as text as part of the PDF extraction (`'with_formatter', 'text'`), it was easier to extract as XML objects then extract the text afterwards.

```
values = pdf.extract([
    #('with_formatter', 'text'),
    ('with_parent','LTPage[pageid=\'1\']'),
    ('values', 'LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("%s,%s,%s,%s")' % ((x1*width_scale), ((800-y)*height_scale), (x*width_scale), ((800-y1)*height_scale)))
])
```

This will result in the dictionary `values` similar to the following:

```
{' values': [<LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextLineHorizontal>]}
```

We can now build a list from the individual `<LTTextLineHorizontal>` XML nodes in `values`:

```
for key,val in values.items():
    if len(val) >= 1: # if we found multiple bbox'
        resultingText = [i.text() for i in val.items('LTTextBoxHorizontal')]
    elif(len(val)) == 1: # if we found only one bbox
        resultingText = [val.text()]
    else: # no bbox found
        resultingText = []
return(resultingText)
```

**The output of `resultingText`:**

```
['Exhibit A Sample Contract', 'Sample Contract']
```